# i have 3 list which i want to print items by order, in a enumerate way

Tags: python, web-scraping, nested-lists

```
    import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
URL= "https://www.monster.com/jobs/search/?q=Software-Developer&where=Australia"
page= requests.get(URL)
soup=BeautifulSoup(page.content, "html.parser")
weak=soup.find(id="SearchResults")
jobname=(weak.find_all(class_="summary"))
jobnamelists=[]
companyname=(weak.find_all(class_="company"))
companynamelists=[]
locations=(weak.find_all(class_="location"))
locationlist=[]
for job in jobname:
    jobnamelists.append(job.find(class_="title").get_text())
for company in companyname:
    companynamelists.append(company.find(class_="name").get_text())
for location in locations:
    locationlist.append(location.find(class_="name").get_text())
```

this is the code, in the end it makes me 3 seperate lists which i scrape from the web,
now i want them to be printed in an enumerated way that the first job will be printed with the first company and the first location
one by one
anyone can help me on that?

Comment: maybe use `zip()`?

Comment: i was thinking about it, but it prints them seperatly, i want item[0] in the joblist to be printed in the same list of item[0] in companynamelist

Comment: If that's what you want, then write a loop and a print statement to do so.  Where are you stuck?

Comment: been searching the web and i found the way to fix it

Comment: ut now it prints it like this 0 ('Resident Engineer (Software) Cyber Security - Sydney\r\n', 'Varmour', '\r\nSydney, NSW\r\n')
1 ('Senior/Lead Software Engineer, Browser\r\n', 'Magic Leap, Inc.', '\r\nSunnyvale, CA; Plantation, FL (HQ); Austin, TX; Culver New York City, CA; Seattle, WA; Toronto, NY\r\n')
and i dont know how to get ridd of \n \r in the list

Answer (score 1):

As stated in the comments, use `zip()` function to iterate over the three lists together. For example:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

URL = "https://www.monster.com/jobs/search/?q=Software-Developer&where=Australia"
page = requests.get(URL)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, "html.parser")

for j, c, l in zip(soup.select('#SearchResults .summary .title'),
                   soup.select('#SearchResults .company .name'),
                   soup.select('#SearchResults .location .name')):
    print(j.get_text(strip=True))
    print(c.get_text(strip=True))
    print(l.get_text(strip=True))
    print('-' * 80)
```

Prints:

```
Resident Engineer (Software) Cyber Security - Sydney
Varmour
Sydney, NSW
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Senior/Lead Software Engineer, Browser
Magic Leap, Inc.
Sunnyvale, CA; Plantation, FL (HQ); Austin, TX; Culver New York City, CA; Seattle, WA; Toronto, NY
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Service Consultant REST
TAL
Sydney, NSW
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

...and so on.
```

Comment: wow thanks alot alot simplified than what i created